# Causing right-click to fire left-click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've found that this code appears to block the right-click pop-up menu:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };
```

However, I need for it to be treated like a left-click. This is used on a form with radio buttons where students are making choices.

---

I think Jeff's solution takes care of the original issue. In conjunction with it, I need an alert-type ok/cancel box to fire when the user clicks a submit button, but I need for it to (1) block the right-click, and (2) ignore keypresses (particularly the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key). Is this doable?

Comment: I should add that I've found alert boxes that ignore keypresses, but I can't determine how to make them ignore right-clicks as well. An examples is at http://www.vrusso.com.br/blog/2011/03/unobtrusive-confirm-javascript-replacement-with-jquery-ui-dialog/

Comment: I've finally wrapped my old head around this. By combining Jeff B's solution at http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/EF47L/1/ with Vicente Russo Neto's prompt box solution at http://www.vrusso.com.br/blog/2011/03/unobtrusive-confirm-javascript-replacement-with-jquery-ui-dialog and tweaking it a bit I have something that I think will work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.target` and `click()`:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
    event.target.click();
    return false;
}
```

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EF47L/

Comment: This works well for the buttons. I need to also prevent right-click on the page to avoid having students get the menu and select to reload the page which messes up things.

Comment: Works on the page, too.  Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: The JSFiddle Demo works on the buttons, but not on the page. FWIW, I'm testing it now using control-click on a Mac, but the students almost all use Windows.

Comment: Ah... what browser are you using?  It works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10+ on Windows.  I am not at my Mac to test.

Comment: Yes, it works on Windows, and on Mac Chrome, but not Safari on my Mac.

Comment: Can you try this version and see if it changes anything? http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/EF47L/1/

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Safari 7.0.  What version are you using?

Comment: Safari 5.1.10 which is likely the issue. Old Mac, stuck on Snow Leopard for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jquery you could trigger a click event for the DOM element.

See http://api.jquery.com/click/

Or Javascript

```
var l = document.getElementById('my-el');
l.onclick();
```